# How to run a SonarQube analysis of .NET Core solution in a Linux container?

Tags: docker, .net-core, sonarqube

I would like to run SonarQube analysis in a Linux container using [their new support](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-sonarscanner) for dotnet global tools. I wonder though where is configuration (server URL, user credentials) located in such case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me nicely:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.300-sdk

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre

RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner --version 4.3.1
COPY SonarQube.Analysis.xml /root/.dotnet/tools/.store/dotnet-sonarscanner/4.3.1/dotnet-sonarscanner/4.3.1/tools/netcoreapp2.1/any/SonarQube.Analysis.xml
ENV PATH="/root/.dotnet/tools:${PATH}"

RUN dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:project-key
RUN dotnet build
RUN dotnet sonarscanner end
```

Obviously, it needs to be build in a context with `SonarQube.Analysis.xml` file present.

Comment: It also works if you pass in settings in the command.  Installing java properly in the image was what I was missing.